# Substituing specific nucleotides in FastaQ files in Linux

Tags: linux, string, awk, bioinformatics

I have some `fastaq` files that I need to analyse. The main issue is that the analysis tool I'm currently working with only accept `ACTG` as nucleotides and not the rest of nomenclatures in the IUPAC code (`R`, `W`, etc).

I've made this code to change the specific nucleotides:

```
awk '{
    split($2,a,"") ; 
    str="" ; 
    for (n in a) {nucleotide=a[n]} ; 
    if (nucleotide~/[ACTG]/) {str=str""nucleotide} 
    else {
        if (nucleotide~/[RWMV]/) {str=str""A} 
        else {
            if (nucleotide~/[YD]/) {str=str""C} 
            else {
                if (nucleotide~/[SKN]/) {str=str""G} 
                else {str=str""T}
            }
        }
    }
}' | head
```

It is working but it is super slow. Do you know a more efficient way to do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `for (n in a) {nucleotide=a[n]} ;` Isn't working well

Comment: Which is your expected output? and example input?

Comment: You don't do anything with the variable `str` at the end

Comment: I know the `fastq` format but not the `fastaq` format

Comment: [the file has quality section?](http://i.imgur.com/bd5xh9q.png) .... after plus symbol

Comment: The input is a fastq file. For example this is what appears in the second line of the file: AGTCGTACTGGACTGYGCSAACTG. The expected output is the same fastq file but changing "Y" for C and the "S" for G. Thank you!

Comment: If you want help from a fastaq expert, you may be on the right track, but if you'd like help from awk experts in general then restricting who can help you to just those who also know whatever fastaq is may not be your best approach. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and don't assume we know anything about your specific domain if you'd like to greatly increase the pool of the people able to help you. `The main issue is that .. only accept ACTG as nucleotides and not the rest of nomenclatures in the IUPAC code` doesn't invite general help.

Comment: why not just use sed:  sed -e 's/Y/C/g' -e 's/S/G/g'

Comment: @grail This doesn't work because of the input format `fastq` .... `sed` solution: `sed '/^@/{n;y/RWMVYDSKN/AAAACCGGG/;}' example.fastq`

Answer (score 3):

For this assuming you have `fastq` format, I recommend to use a specialized library, `biopython` or `bioperl` are good options.

> cat example.fastq

```
@ID
AGTCGTACTGGACTGYGCSAACTG
+
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@ID2
RWMVYDSKNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

However, solution using `awk`

```
awk 'NR%4==2{gsub(/[RWMV]/,"A"); gsub(/[YD]/,"C"); gsub(/[SKN]/,"G")}1' example.fastq
```

you get,

```
@ID
AGTCGTACTGGACTGCGCGAACTG
+
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@ID2
AAAACCGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

Comment: I initially thought in to use `sed` .... `sed '/^@/{n;y/RWMVYDSKN/AAAACCGGG/;}' example.fastq ` ....

Comment: @Inian `sub()` only modifies the first occurrence, It doesn't work in this case

Comment: Ahh! Now I remember!